# Need towerjs "Mailers" working example

Tags: node.js, mailer, towerjs

I reed [Tower.js](http://towerjs.org/) doc and totally cant see - how I may get worked mailer?

Mailers section said:

```
class App.Notification extends Tower.Mailer
  # app/views/mailers/welcome.coffee template
  @welcome: (user) ->
    @mail to: user.email, from: "me@gmail.com"
```

but example do not marked where this code need to be placed.

Please appoint me.

Comment: Bear in mind Tower is under heavy construction and this feature may not yet be fully implemented. I haven't personally tried to use it, so I don't know, but if you cannot get it to work, you might want to look at the source code and see if the implementation for mailers looks complete.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the mailer should go in `app/mailers`, based on [the generator for mailers](https://github.com/viatropos/tower/blob/026416121143dd9a7caf35e9dd1ec5e3ca195dae/src/tower/server/generator/generators/tower/mailer/mailerGenerator.coffee):

```coffee-script
class Tower.Generator.MailerGenerator extends Tower.Generator
  sourceRoot: __dirname

  run: ->
    @inside "app", '.', ->
      @inside "mailers", '.', ->
        @template "mailer.coffee", "#{@model.name}Mailer.coffee", ->

module.exports = Tower.Generator.MailerGenerator
```